# Why does Pylance show error for one function with type hints but not the other?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, type-hinting, pylance

VSCode Pylance v2023.9.20 with strict checking is giving me type error on first function call, but not the second. Only difference is that in first argument is wrapped in list.

```
def listTupleFunc(arg: list[tuple[str, tuple[str, ...]]]) -> None:
    pass
listTuple = [('x', ('a', 'b'))]
listTupleFunc(listTuple) # Error here

def tupleOnlyFunc(arg: tuple[str, tuple[str, ...]]) -> None:
    pass
tupleOnly = ('x', ('a', 'b'))
tupleOnlyFunc(tupleOnly) # OK
```

And the error message is:

```
Argument of type "list[tuple[Literal['x'], tuple[Literal['a'], Literal['b']]]]" cannot be assigned to parameter "arg" of type "list[tuple[str, tuple[str, ...]]]" in function "listTupleFunc"
  "list[tuple[Literal['x'], tuple[Literal['a'], Literal['b']]]]" is incompatible with "list[tuple[str, tuple[str, ...]]]"
    Type parameter "_T@list" is invariant, but "tuple[Literal['x'], tuple[Literal['a'], Literal['b']]]" is not the same as "tuple[str, tuple[str, ...]]"
```

If I change so that *some* of the literals are formatted, suprisingly the error disappears:

```
# These work OK somehow
listTuple = [(f'x', ('a', f'b'))]  
listTuple = [(f'x', (f'a', 'b'))]  
# But these don't
listTuple = [('x', (f'a', f'b'))]
listTuple = [(f'x', ('a', 'b'))]
```

Is this a bug in Pylance or am I missing something obvious? How do I get rid of the error?

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the `listTuple` to required type.

```py
def listTupleFunc(arg: list[tuple[str, tuple[str, ...]]]) -> None:
    pass
listTuple: list[tuple[str, tuple[str, ...]]] = [('x', ('a', 'b'))]
listTupleFunc(listTuple) # No error!

def tupleOnlyFunc(arg: tuple[str, tuple[str, ...]]) -> None:
    pass
tupleOnly = ('x', ('a', 'b'))
tupleOnlyFunc(tupleOnly) # OK
```

This removes the error. PyLance expects these hard coded literals as being incompetable with the general definition you used.

Comment: this is not a cast.

Comment: English is not my first language. Feel free to suggest an edit.

Comment: you are just explicitly type annotating. the approach is correct though

Answer (score 1):

So, the error message is quite descriptive. When you do just:

```
listTuple = [('x', ('a', 'b'))]
```

Then the type inference rules of pyright infer:

```
list[tuple[Literal['x'], tuple[Literal['a'], Literal['b']]]]
```

Now, you may argue, "but `tuple[Literal['x'], tuple[Literal['a'], Literal['b']]` is a subtype of `tuple[str, tuple[str, ...]]`, it should be accepted here!

But look at the rest of the error message, it points out, `list` is *invariant*. So if you have `list[T]`, and `list[S]` and `S` is a subtype of `T`, then **`list[S]` is not a subtype of `list[T]`!** as you might expect

People tend to expect parametrized types to be *covariant*.

`list` objects have to be invariant because they are mutable (read more about this in [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#covariance-and-contravariance)).

Consider the following toy example:

```
class T:
    pass

class S(T):
    pass

s = S() # inferring type S
reveal_type(s)

t: T = s # OK!

data_s = [S(), S()] # inferring type list[s]
reveal_type(data_s)

data_t: list[T] =  data_s # Whoops!
```

Here is what `pyright` says on my machine:

```
jarrivillaga-mbp16-2019:scratch jarrivillaga$ pyright test_typing.py 
No configuration file found.
No pyproject.toml file found.
stubPath /Users/jarrivillaga/scratch/typings is not a valid directory.
Assuming Python platform Darwin
Searching for source files
Found 1 source file
/Users/jarrivillaga/scratch/test_typing.py
  /Users/jarrivillaga/scratch/test_typing.py:8:13 - info: Type of "s" is "S"
  /Users/jarrivillaga/scratch/test_typing.py:13:13 - info: Type of "data_s" is "list[S]"
  /Users/jarrivillaga/scratch/test_typing.py:15:20 - error: Expression of type "list[S]" cannot be assigned to declared type "list[T]"
    TypeVar "_T@list" is invariant
      "S" is incompatible with "T" (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
1 error, 0 warnings, 2 infos 
Completed in 0.495sec
```

So one solution is to *annotate the variable explicitly with the super type and don't rely on type inference*, in the toy example:

```
data_s: list[T] = [S(), S()] # don't rely on inference!
```

Or for your code:

```
listTuple: tuple[str, tuple[str, ...]] = [('x', ('a', 'b'))]
```

Another alternative, if you don't need to rely on any of the *mutator* methods for `list` (like `.append` or `.pop`, or `mlist[i] = whatever`) then you can use `collections.abc.Sequence`, which is *covariant*:

```
from collections.abc import Sequence

class T:
    pass

class S(T):
    pass

s = S() # inferring type S
reveal_type(s)

t: T = s # OK!

data_s = [S(), S()] # inferring type list[s]
reveal_type(data_s)

data_t: Sequence[T] =  data_s # covariance, yay!
```

Now pyright is satisfied:

```
jarrivillaga-mbp16-2019:scratch jarrivillaga$ pyright test_typing.py 
No configuration file found.
No pyproject.toml file found.
stubPath /Users/jarrivillaga/scratch/typings is not a valid directory.
Assuming Python platform Darwin
Searching for source files
Found 1 source file
/Users/jarrivillaga/scratch/test_typing.py
  /Users/jarrivillaga/scratch/test_typing.py:10:13 - info: Type of "s" is "S"
  /Users/jarrivillaga/scratch/test_typing.py:15:13 - info: Type of "data_s" is "list[S]"
0 errors, 0 warnings, 2 infos 
Completed in 0.489sec
```

Comment: This is interesting, but it does raise one question: Why did messing with strings sometimes make errors go away? It shouldn't have any effect based on what you described. Is Pylance missing an obvious error here?

Comment: `f"x"` is not a string literal, but a `str`. This naturally fits the required annotation in the cases you've listed.

Comment: @user694733 I believe *all of those cases should actually fail*, so those are examples of *false negatives*. I believe the issue was just recently addressed here: https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/5999 so if I understand correctly, these should all fail in version v1.1.329 (which was just published on github like 25 minutes ago...)

Comment: @vahvero it is actually a string literal, pyright even infers it as such